# Visual Studio 2015 No Publish To Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

There is no option to publish my ASP.NET Core app to Azure on the publish context menu. I did have an update to Visual Studio 2015 recently:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.8
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.8.31121.1

Is there a problem with this version?

I have 
Microsoft Azure Tools   2.8
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.8.31121.1

Comment: I have re-installed VS2015 but it still no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is lose in your Visual Studio, when I try to publish it, I have all the options:

[image]

I have the Azure SDK 2.9, alsio check you have the latest version for the Microsoft ASPNET and Web tools (now, I have the version 14)

Comment: I have 
Microsoft Azure Tools   2.8
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.8.31121.1

Answer (score -1):

I updated the Azure SDK to :

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.40701.9

The publish option has now appeared.